# Internal Server Error (Server Error)

Tags: error-message

My home page and some inner pages work fine but some page is not working and when i click on it then its showing me " Internal Server Error Server Error"

Please help me to sort out this issue.

Comment: If it's a Craft-styled 500 Internal Server Error page, then the underlying error message should be in the Craft `storage/logs` folder (if this is Craft 3) or `craft/storage/runtime/logs` folder (if this is Craft 2). If it's a web-server styled error page, then it should be in your web server's error logs. I'd start by checking those.

Comment: Also you might get more info about the issue if you set `ENVIRONMENT="dev"` in your .env file in the root of your project